# What does "current to one year" mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw in a graduate admission webpage [English Language Proficiency Requirements](https://www.duq.edu/academics/schools/natural-and-environmental-sciences/academics/departments-and-programs/physics/professional-masters-degree-in-applied-physics/admissions?fbclid=IwAR39ZSELbjBRDG-sR_tfwkSTlT0ZfJDOTMamQD_LUeWu-v_6Xod4VDi_s5c) that the TOEFL score date is "current to one year". What does the phrase mean? Current until last year?

Comment: Please post a link to the page. It's an unusual phrase. Some context would be helpful.

Comment: Googling the string ***current to one year*** returns plenty of results associated with things like X-rays, tests for specific diseases, etc. So the likely intended meaning is *[TOEFL score data] **which is "current", no more than one year old***. You'll find a handful of results for ***current to two years*** to confirm that perspective. But it's not exactly an "established" usage - more like "jargon".

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica, https://www.duq.edu/academics/schools/natural-and-environmental-sciences/academics/departments-and-programs/physics/professional-masters-degree-in-applied-physics/admissions?fbclid=IwAR39ZSELbjBRDG-sR_tfwkSTlT0ZfJDOTMamQD_LUeWu-v_6Xod4VDi_s5c

Comment: Good *afternoon*, @Mark! (I'm in the UK, and I don't do mornings myself any more anyway! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click through the link on the page that you linked to, you will reach a paragraph [English Placement Test Requirements for ALL Students](https://www.duq.edu/academics/degrees-and-programs/english-as-a-second-language/language-policies) where it says

> Students who submit official scores, current to within one year, of
> 90 or higher on the Internet-based Test of English as a Foreign
> Language TOEFL (iBT), or an equivalent score on earlier versions of
> the TOEFL, are excused from English Placement Tests except for tests
> of written and spoken English.

Current to within one year means results that have been obtained within the last year.  Reading between the lines, it seems that scores are calculated differently now  than they used to be (hence "equivalent" score).  It's not very obvious though what they are trying to say. Maybe someone more familiar with the TOEFL system needs to answer.

Comment: Interesting.  The TOEFL information is in hard-to-understand English.

Comment: @GEdgar  - Maybe that is the *real* test. If you can understand their English well enough to fill in the form, then they consider your English good enough!